# input field weird bug in iOs and Firefox (only devices)

Tags: jquery

I have a search input field at the top of my website that hides when I scroll down (top is fixed). When I click on the search button, the input field will show again.

Now the problem is that when I click on the input field when scrolled down, my whole page scrolls up to the original position of the input field and then shows the keyboard.

The input field is the same as the one on the top, so I'm not sure why it scrolls all the way up to the top.

The 'weird' thing is that it works perfectly on Chrome and desktop.

TL;DR: When I try to click on input field, it scrolls all the way up to the original position.

HTML:

```
<header class="top">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="logo">
            <a href="{$basedir}" title="{'Go to home'|lang}" class="main-logo">
                <img src="{$basedir}images/common/logo.png" width="150" height="50" alt="{$siteName|escape}" data-highres-url="{$basedir}images/common/logo@2x.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="search">
            {include file="form/search.tpl"}
        </div>

    </div>

</header>
<div id="nav-toggle-container">
    <a id="nav-toggle-btn" class="visible-xs visible-sm" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(function()
{
    var $header = $('header.top');

    var $input = $header.find('input[type=search]');
    var $search = $header.find('div.search');
    var $searchContainer = $header.find('div.input-group')
    var $searchBtn = $search.find('button.icon-search');
    var $closeBtn = $search.find('span.icon-cross');
    var $window = $(window);
    var $document = $(document);

    $closeBtn.css('display', 'none');

    function smallTopCheck()
    {
        if ($window.width() < 992)
        {
            $document.on('scroll', function()
            {
                if ($document.scrollTop() > 20)
                {
                    // Turn top into small menu
                    $header.addClass('small');

                    // Prevent search button to search
                    $searchBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    // Open search bar when clicking button
                    $document.on('click', '.icon-search', function () {
                        $searchBtn.off('click');
                        $searchContainer.addClass('search-open');
                        $input.val("");
                        /*$input.focus();*/

                    });

                    // Close search bar when clicking button
                    $document.on('click', '.icon-cross', function () {
                        $searchBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        $searchContainer.removeClass('search-open');
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // Reverse small menu
                    $header.removeClass('small');

                    if($searchContainer.hasClass("search-open"))
                    {
                        $searchContainer.removeClass('search-open');
                    }

                    // Return search function
                    $searchBtn.off('click');
                    $document.off('click', '.icon-search');
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove small top
            if($header.hasClass("small"))
            {
                $header.removeClass("small");
            }

            if($searchContainer.hasClass("search-open"))
            {
                $searchContainer.removeClass('search-open');
            }

            $window.off('scroll');
        }
    }

    smallTopCheck();

    // if window is resized check again

    var doneResizing;
    $( window ).resize(function()
    {
        window.clearTimeout(doneResizing);
        doneResizing = window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            smallTopCheck();
        }, 250)
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some piece of code we could play with ?

Comment: Sure, I added my Jquery code.

Comment: oops, that won't be enough :) Can you also give a simplified version of your HTML file ?

Comment: I added the html code, I use Smarty which explains the {} in the code and search.tpl is just a form with the search input and search span, not sure if it's necessary